# Can we add comment on photos,albums via facebook api?

Tags: php, api, facebook

Is it possible to to add comment on photo or album via facebook api?
And if possible please specify me the way.
Thank you guys in advance ;)

Answer (score 7):

Using the [PHP-SDK](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk):

```
$facebook->api("/PHOTO_ID/comments","POST",array("message"=>"test comment"));
```

[image]

Comment: But i want to add comment by any other users name not by my.then?And can we also add "likes" like this?